# MagicalRecord - shorthand works for some entities but not others

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

In my prefix file I have this:

```
#define MR_SHORTHAND
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"


//this causes an unrecognized selector sent to instance crash
Apple *apple = [Face findFirstByAttribute:@"appleId" withValue:value];

//this works fine
Apple *apple = [Face MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"appleId" withValue:value];

//however this also works fine:
Orange *orange = [Face findFirstByAttribute:@"orangeId" withValue:value];
```

Why would I be able to use shorthand with some entities and not with others?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem. Only just started happening though. Very strange, did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know if this is any help to you but I just fixed the problem I was having.

I had an entity called "EventMessage" and I didn't like the name so I renamed it to "Message".

This is when I started having the problems.

It was only running the app to the simulator from AppCode that I saw a message telling me that "Message is implemented twice".

I renamed the entity (and all the associated classes) back to "EventMessage" and it's working fine now.

Strange that it even compiled before though?!

Anyway, give that a go. Rename your Face entity to something that you know is unique "SoleilFace" for example and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I just encountered this same problem - did you find an answer?

Comment: Yes, rename the entity to something that is definitely unique and not reserved. What's your entity name?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this search result in the year 2014 and for version 2.2+, the Cocapod you need to install to use shorthand is

`pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand',    '~> 2.2';`

As per the following thread

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/668